# How to paste CSV data to Windows Clipboard with C#

Tags: c#, windows, csv, clipboard, paste

### What I'm trying to accomplish

- My app generates some tabular data
- I want the user to be able to launch Excel and click "paste" to place the data as cells in Excel
- Windows accepts a format called "CommaSeparatedValue" that is used with it's APIs so this seems possible
- Putting raw text on the clipboard works, but trying to use this format does not
- NOTE: I can correctly retrieve CSV data from the clipboard, my problem is about pasting CSV data to the clipboard.

### What I have tried that isn't working

Clipboard.SetText()

```
System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(  
  "1,2,3,4\n5,6,7,8", 
  System.Windows.Forms.TextDataFormat.CommaSeparatedValue
  );
```

Clipboard.SetData()

```
System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetData(
  System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue,
  "1,2,3,4\n5,6,7,8", 
  );
```

In both cases something is placed on the clipboard, but when pasted into Excel it shows up as one cell of garbarge text: "–§žý;pC¦yVk²ˆû"

### Update 1: Workaround using SetText()

As BFree's answer shows **SetText** with **TextDataFormat** serves as a workaround

```
System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(  
  "1\t2\t3\t4\n5\t6\t7\t8", 
  System.Windows.Forms.TextDataFormat.Text
  );
```

I have tried this and confirm that now pasting into Excel and Word works correctly. In each case it pastes as a table with cells instead of plaintext.

Still curious why CommaSeparatedValue is *not* working.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The .NET Framework places `DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue` on the clipboard as Unicode text. But as mentioned at http://www.syncfusion.com/faq/windowsforms/faq_c98c.aspx#q899q, Excel expects CSV data to be a UTF-8 memory stream (it is difficult to say whether .NET or Excel is at fault for the incompatibility).

The solution I've come up with in my own application is to place two versions of the tabular data on the clipboard simultaneously as tab-delimited text and as a CSV memory stream. This allows the destination application to acquire the data in its preferred format. Notepad and Excel prefer the tab-delimited text, but you can force Excel to grab the CSV data via the Paste Special... command for testing purposes.

Here is some example code (note that WinForms-equivalents from the WPF namespaces are used here):

```
// Generate both tab-delimited and CSV strings.
string tabbedText = //...
string csvText = //...

// Create the container object that will hold both versions of the data.
var dataObject = new System.Windows.DataObject();

// Add tab-delimited text to the container object as is.
dataObject.SetText(tabbedText);

// Convert the CSV text to a UTF-8 byte stream before adding it to the container object.
var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(csvText);
var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes);
dataObject.SetData(System.Windows.DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue, stream);

// Copy the container object to the clipboard.
System.Windows.Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObject, true);
```

Comment: Any thoughts about how those of us not on .net might do this? Is it maybe possible if you're willing to jump headlong into appdomain/marshalling/com-object rules? Maybe I'll just stick to `/t` as per the other answers.

Comment: Excel does not need a stream, just put the UTF8 bytes in there directly. Not disposing the MemoryStream might cause a memory leak.

Comment: Excel may be expecting UTF8 BOM, if you use StreamWriter or  new UTF8Encoding(false) ctor it will add it. By the way tab separated text work but CommaSeparatedValue ignored for(

Answer (score 7):

Use tabs instead of commas. ie:

```
Clipboard.SetText("1\t2\t3\t4\t3\t2\t3\t4", TextDataFormat.Text);
```

Just tested this myself, and it worked for me.

Comment: I tried the CSV method and wasn't able to get it to work either - looks like using tabs is the way to go.

Comment: Good to know that excel is more forgiving about tabs in this regard.

Comment: Be careful with this because Excel will try to interpret values beginning with operators like *, +, - as formulas.  I'm not sure whether CSV will get around this either.

Comment: CSV doesn't get around this. :(

Answer (score 4):

I have had success pasting into Excel using \t (see BFree's answer) as column separators and \n as row separators.

Answer (score 0):

I got the most success defeating formatting issues by using a CSV library ([KBCsv](https://github.com/kentcb/KBCsv)) to write the data into a CSV file in the temp folder then open it in Excel with `Process.Start()`. Once it is in Excel the formatting bit is easy(er), copy-paste from there.

```cs
string filePath = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".csv";

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(filePath))
using (CsvWriter csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter))
{
    // optional header
    csvWriter.WriteRecord(new List<string>(){"Heading1", "Heading2", "YouGetTheIdea" });

    csvWriter.ValueSeparator = ',';
    foreach (var thing in YourListOfThings ?? new List<OfThings>())
    {
        if (thing != null)
        {
            List<string> csvLine = new List<string>
                                         {
                                             thing.Property1, thing.Property2, thing.YouGetTheIdea
                                         };

            csvWriter.WriteRecord(csvLine);
        }
    }
}

Process.Start(filePath);
```

BYO Error handing & logging.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround Use ["Html Format"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.windows.dataformats.html?view=windowsdesktop-8.0#system-windows-dataformats-html) write html <table> and surround with  [special header](https://theartofdev.com/2014/06/12/setting-htmltext-to-clipboard-revisited/)